# CodeIgniter get values back if validation fails

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I am new at codeigniter and I got a question. I have a form with validation and that works fine, but say if I enter data in a field and leave the rest blank, the validation will show me the errors and clear the data that has been entered....how do I fix this?

Here is my controller code:

```
function submitclub()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $dataclub['clubname'] = $this->club_model->get(0, FALSE);
            $dataclub['division'] = $this->division_model->get(0, FALSE);
            $data['reset'] = TRUE;
            $view = 'individual/individual_view';
        }
```

Any help would be much apperciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing this in my view:

```
<?php echo form_input('lastname', set_value('lastname'), 'id=lastname'); ?>
<?php echo form_error('lastname'); ?>
```